# Custom ComboBox focus doesn't shift to select elem and eventBubble doesn't stop. Works fine in IE but not on others

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Here I have created a custom combobox where user can select values from the dropdown either by clicking on the arrow image given beside the input text field or by clicking on the text field.

This code is working fine on IE 11. On Google Chrome, when i click on the arrow image I am able to select the value from the dropdown. But when I click on the text field, I am not able to select the values.

Here the onclick event gets fired properly, but the input text(combo-box) opens the dropdown and the focus doesn't shift to the dropdown. Now as the focus is not there on the dropdown, chrome behaves weirdly and doesn't select the option when I click on it.
Now, when I try to shift the focus by coding to the dropdown, then the input onblur event gets fired and the dropdown closes.

So basically it doesn't open.

I have tried this on JSFiddle but it doesn't replicate on IE. I would suggest you to use pastebin link http://pastebin.com/aGmT0srm and test it on your machine.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/n0369z7j/5/)

```
<select size="8" name="sel_vData_30" id="sel_vData_30" style="display:none;"        
       onblur="comboselect_onblur(vData_30,this)" 
       onchange="comboselect_onchange(this, vData_30)" 
       onkeyup="comboselect_onkeyup(13, this, vData_30)"        
       onclick="comboselect_onchange(this, vData_30)" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Office">Office</option>
    <option value="Plant">Plant</option>
    <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
    <option value="Service Technician">Service Technician</option>
    <option value="Transportation">Transportation</option>
</select>
```

I want this to work on cross browser especially on Chrome.

Any insights or suggestions are welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> But when I click on the text field, I am not able to select the
>   values.

Removing the `onblur="combotext_onblur(vData_30,sel_vData_30)"` from your `<input>` fixes the described issue for `IE 11`, `FF 38` and `Chrome 43`.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n0369z7j/6/

Comment: Thank you @Ivan. I need the blur event to remove the focus and select which ever option was hightlighted/hover from the combo box field when I click anywhere outside (body). That stops working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via custom code but it is fairly complex as the browser compatibilities are difficult to take care of for default form elements.

Its better recommended to use already tested and maintained js plugin like:

http://select2.github.io/examples.html

Your code will be much **cleaner** and **efficient**.